# Bounds of integration for $E[\frac{X}{Y}]$. $X,Y$ are exponential r.v. with parameter alpha and beta.

Tags: expected-value, exponential-distribution, bounds-of-integration

Let $X,Y$ be Exponential random variables with parameter alpha=lambda and beta=mu. Assume $t=u$.

> **Appendix: Evaluation of the integral:**
>   \begin{align}
> f_{X/Y}(u) = {} & \alpha\beta \int_0^\infty e^{-(\alpha u+\beta)y} y \, dy \\[8pt]
> = {} & \frac{\alpha\beta}{(\alpha u+\beta)^2} \int_0^\infty e^{-(\alpha u+\beta)y} (\alpha u+\beta) y \big( (\alpha u + \beta) \, dy \big) \\[8pt]
> = {} & \frac{\alpha\beta}{(\alpha u+\beta)^2} \int_0^\infty e^{-v} v \,dv \\[8pt]
> = {} & \frac{\alpha\beta}{(\alpha u+\beta)^2}.
> \end{align}
>
> $$\mathbb E\left[\frac{X}{Y}\right]=\int uf_{\frac{X}{Y}}(u)du$$

What are the limits of integration on $u$?

Someone told me that the limits of integration are from zero to infinity.

I don't believe them and I think instead, the limits of integration are from zero to $\frac{x}{y}$ 
I understand the expected value yields an real number and using x/y as the upper bound wouldn't give me an integral convergent to some real number but that's not a great explanation. 
.

because of the bounds on the integral where $t=u$

> For $t>0$ we have
>   $$\begin{align}
> \mathbb P\left(\frac XY>t\right) &= \iint_{\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\ :\ 0\leqslant ty\leqslant x\}} \lambda\mu e^{-\lambda x}e^{-\mu y}\end{align}$$

I'm looking at the bounds on $ty$ which gives me the bounds for $t$ or $u$.

Comment: The dependency information is not clear.  What is meant  by $\alpha = \lambda$ and $\beta = \mu$? What is meant by $t=u$?

Comment: TFAE: alpha and lambda. TFAE: beta and mu.

Comment: Now I am more confused.  I do not know what TFAE means.

Comment: The following are equivalent.

Comment: You seem to be assuming some joint distribution that depends on $\alpha, \beta, \lambda, \mu, t, u$ and/or you cannot make up your mind about what parameters to use.  Eventually a joint distribution function should be given and/or a dependency relationship between $X$ and $Y$ specified.

Comment: $X, Y \in [0,\infty)$, therefore $X/Y \in [0,\infty)$ so long as you have independence. So $[0,\infty)$ is the right limit